# Login into webpage and load a link using IOS Shortcuts

Tags: javascript, ios, shortcut

I'm trying to create a shortcut to login into my gym webpage and load a QR code in my account to access the place.

On pc, it works correctly:

```
1 - Open: https://www.donostia.eus/donostiakirola/kirolekintzak/login.aspx
2 - Run Javascript on current safari tab
       var result = [];

       var usuario = "user";
       var password = "pass";

       document.getElementById("MainContent_MainContent_a2txtCodigo_txtA2TextBox").value = usuario;
       document.getElementById("MainContent_MainContent_a2txtPassword_txtA2TextBox").value = password;
       document.getElementById("MainContent_MainContent_btnLogin").click();

       completion(result);

3 - Open: https://www.donostia.eus/donostiakirola/kirolekintzak/QR.aspx
```

The problem is that it doesn't work on iPhone.

Any idea why?